# when deploying a system in 64bits using mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem my project made in vb2008 .net and using 32bit proccessor architecture and using mysql as a back end. And mysql.data and mysql odbc connector. In 32 bit architecture my system is working very well. But when i deploy it in 64bit i cant connect to database.. but i can open the database using the mysql administrator or mysql browser. And i got error "the type initializer for  threw an exception" this is when checking if the connection state is close. Please help me.. sorry for bad english

Comment: Are you deploying the MySQL library(ies) with your app or are they installed separately?  What is the Target Platform in the project properties?

Comment: I installed separately.  any cpu the target platform.

Comment: It sounds as though the bittedness of your app and the library are not the same.  If the Target Platform is Any CPU then your app will be running in a 64-bit process.  Does that machine perhaps only have the 32-bit version of the MySQL library installed?

Comment: Yes the mysql does not have 64bit installer.. so i installed mysql 32bit.. is there any way to fix my problem??

Comment: I don't use MySQL or develop on a 32-bit machine so I can't claim to have done this successfully myself, but I'd suggest changing the `Copy Local` property of your MySQL reference to `True` and then deploy the library with your app. That should deploy the correct version with your app if it's possible. If that doesn't work then that would suggest that your app will have to be targeted at the x86 platform to run in a 32-bit process, which I didn't think was required for MySQL.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps by steps on how to change the copy local property??

Comment: How do you normally change a property? You select the thing whose property you want to change, you open the Properties window and you set the value of the desired property.

Comment: Thanks i got it.. :-)